# Interface model binding on post - generic list member

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Having the following model:

```
public class SomeModelAttribute<T> : ISomeModel {
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public T Value { get; set; }
}

public class SomeModel {
   public IEnumerable<ISomeModel> Attributes { get; set; }
}
```

When I'm making a post request to `public JsonResult SaveModel(SomeModel model){ ... }` I get the following exception: `Cannot create an instance of an interface.`

It's common sense to get this error but is there a way to make this work similar to how the model binder creates a List out of IEnumerable? So that I could have inside my SomeModel posted instance a list of SomeModelAttribute ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution: custom model binder.
Created a custom model binder as follows:

```
public class SomeModelModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
     public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
     {
         if (bindingContext.ModelType == typeof(ISomeModel))
         {
             HttpRequestBase request = controllerContext.HttpContext.Request;
             bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName + ".Value");

             [some logic to return a new SomeModelAttribute<something>();]
         }
         else
         {
             return base.BindModel(controllerContext, bindingContext);
         }
     }
}
```

Added ModelBinder attribute on ISomeModel so that we specify the custom binder that it has to be used:

```
[ModelBinder(typeof(SomeModelModelBinder))]
public interface ISomeModel { ... }
```

Et voila ... works like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

Model binding tries to create instance before binding it. We cannot create instance from interface use secondary object which implements ISomeModel.